# Can we get a website or web app from a react-native project?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, react-native-web

My question is simple. I have a basic react-native project, generated from Expo as a Bare WOrkflow app.

Expo Managed Workflow gives a web version of the app.

How can this be implemented in a bare React Native app? I can't find decent documentation anywhere. I have tried [react-native-web docs](https://necolas.github.io/react-native-web/docs/), but I haven't been able to implement them.

Comment: i just asked to google [tutorial](https://blog.logrocket.com/react-native-web-complete-tutorial/)

Comment: I found that link and ignored it. After your comment, I revisited it and tried it, but not to success. Did you try it yourself?

Comment: yes that works for me, but indeed I just followed the tutorial and I had to change the configuration of webpack, we agree you are on a react-native app not expo?

Comment: I used expo init, and then picked "bare workflow". That is suggested for projects involving native code. Should I go with a basic react-native project?

Answer (score 1):

So starting from a basic installation of react-native app with the command

`npx react-native init newProject`

#### installation of dependencies

> i use yarn but for npm is `npm i -D myLib` instead of `yarn add -D myLib`

For react we need:

`yarn add react react-dom react-native-web`

For Webpack we need:

`yarn add -D webpack webpack-cli babel-loader webpack-dev-server`

#### Webpack configuration

> in the root folder create a file with name **webpack.config.js**
> And a folder with name **public** is the output folder

```
//webpack.config.js
const path = require("path");

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    main: "./index.web.js",
  },

  mode: "development",

  devtool: "inline-source-map",

  devServer: {
    writeToDisk: true,
    liveReload: true,
  },

  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: "babel-loader",
      },
    ],
  },
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      "react-native": "react-native-web",
    },
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "public"),
  },
};
```

**And a index.html in a root folder**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Testing on the Web!</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta content="initial-scale=1,width=device-width" name="viewport" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="react-native-app"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/public/main.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

#### The index.web.js for test in the root folder

```
import React, {Component} from "react";
import {AppRegistry, StyleSheet, Text, View} from "react-native";

class ReactNativeWeb extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.welcome}>Welcome to React Native!</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
    backgroundColor: "#142a3d",
  },
  welcome: {
    fontSize: 20,
    textAlign: "center",
    margin: 10,
    color: "#ffffff",
  },
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent("ReactNativeWeb", () => ReactNativeWeb);
AppRegistry.runApplication("ReactNativeWeb", {
  rootTag: document.getElementById("react-native-app"),
});
```

#### Script package.json

> we add a command in package.json for launch the build and the webpack server

```
{
...
"scripts": {
 ...
 "web": "webpack serve --progress --config webpack.config.js"
}
...
}
```

**And now, launch the command**
`yarn web`

Open from a browser `http://localhost:8080/`

**Note that the webpack configuration only serves javascript files, you will have to add rules for other file types**